# Java: String.toCharArray() with unicode characters

Tags: java, string, char, arrays

I know that char cannot contain Unicode characters (like char c = '\u1023'). So how would I go about doing

```
    String s = "ABCDEFG\u1023";
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
```

I would like to convert s to a CharArray for performance reasons as I have to loop through every character in a potentially very long string which is inefficient. Anything which achieves the same result is fine.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Actually char can contain unicode chars. I'm just being stupid. Thanks to those who helped out anyway.

Comment: actually. `char c = '\u1023'` works for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whoever told you that in Java `char` can't contain Unicode characters, [was wrong](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1):

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>
> - For `char`, from `'\u0000'` to `'\uffff'` inclusive, that is, from 0 to
>     65535

Comment: Oh thanks. Ok that sorts out a lot of problems. I must have been thinking about something else. I will accept this as the answer in a few minutes. (SO isn't letting me yet!)

Answer (score 5):

Three things:

1. A char most certainly *can* have u1023.
2. `toCharArray()` will return a char array that is virtually the same as UTF16
3. Since a char is 16 bit, and the Unicode spans 21 bits, the characters outside the BMP are encoded as two surrogate chars. Java 1.5 onwards has APIs for this, for example [`String.codePointAt(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29). If you are using Java 1.4 or earlier, look into ICU4J.

Answer (score 3):

Java `char` can contain [the most](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) Unicode characters as the others have already mentioned, but the characters outside of Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) are split into multiple `char`s and handling them independently might break the string.

To be safe you can split the string into string array:

```
String[] c = s.codePoints()
    .mapToObj(cp -> new String(Character.toChars(cp)))
    .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```

... or use [`isSurrogate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isSurrogate-char-), [`isLowSurrogate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowSurrogate-char-) and [`isHighSurrogate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isHighSurrogate-char-) methods of `Character` object to prevent alteration of a single `char` within the pair:

```
Character.isSurrogate('a');
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, a char is essentially an unsigned short.  In order to iterate through a string that has unicode characters outside of the range supported by char (the first 65536), you should use the following pattern, which stores each codepoint as an int.

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length();) {
    int ch = str.codePointAt(i);
    // do stuff with ch...
    i += Character.charCount(ch);
}
```

Java was designed with first-class support for the first 65536 characters, which at the time was an improvement over C/C++, which had first-class support for only the first 128 or 256 characters.  Unfortunately, it means that the above pattern is necessary in Java to support the out-of-range characters that are becoming more common.