# How to draw a unicode character in java?

Tags: java, unicode

Short of copying the character to the clipboard and pasting it inside my string, is there a way to draw a greek letter (or for that matter, any unicode character)? I know the code for the character I am trying to draw is `U+03F4` according to [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/#03F4). I have tried the following:

```
g.drawString("U+03F4", 100, 100); // works as a string literal as it should
g.drawString("\U+03F4", 100, 100); // error: Illegal escape character
g.drawString("\\U+03F4", 100, 100); // thought I could trick it. Just draws "\U+03F4"
```

I saw in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652244/java-string-tochararray-with-unicode-characters) question that the 'u' was lowercase but that didn't make any difference.

Why would this not be working?

Comment: Also, be sure that the font you're using supports those characters ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The general format for Java unicode escapes is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21523055/139010)

```
UnicodeEscape:
    \ UnicodeMarker HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit

UnicodeMarker:
    u
    UnicodeMarker u
```

Therefore correct sequence for this character in Java is `\u03F4`.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03F4/index.htm

Answer (score 4):

I think the correct way to represent a unicode character is as follows:

```
g.drawString("\u03f4", 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
g.drawString("\u03f4", 100, 100);
```

if you want to get a `char`, use `'\u03f4'`, but in this case use double quotes since you want it to be a `String`.