# Font for Unicode

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, jtable

I'm programming a GUI with a table to show the unicode-characters, but with the standard font it will display instead of the unicode-character a square box.

With what fonts can i display all that characters if possible of all languages?

[image]

Usually I do not declare a font, only I need it, but not in this case.

It would be nice if someone knows a solution.

Thanks in advance for your answers :D

Comment: How are you coding your gui?

Comment: What do you mean with "How I'm coding that?"

Comment: You don't need stackoverflow to find a list of fonts that, taken together, span all of unicode. There are plenty of web search results that will help you on your way.

Comment: What language are you using to create your gui? is it in HTML/Java/.net?
Share the code that you are using to achieve this.
How are you setting the font to the table?

Comment: In the tags you can see that I'm using java. Curretly I'm using the standart font.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your picture. But usually those squares come when you want a character that is not existed in your font or you have some problem in your unicode encoding.
either you can use more comprehensive font (TrueType) or check your data to be encoded correctly.
see these for further info on Java & Unicodes.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html

https://www.javatpoint.com/unicode-system-in-java

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Unicode

an example would be :

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0419__PDF/Usetruetypefonttodrawunicodestring.htm

[How to draw a unicode character in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215110/how-to-draw-a-unicode-character-in-java)

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/Drawunicodestring.htm

Comment: I know how to declare Unicode, but need some fonts whit that I can display if possible all characters.

Comment: what language you need to display? also can you provide some code you using ?

Comment: If possible I want to display every language also if I need more than one font. I tryed to provide some code, but i don't know what exactly you want to see. ;)